# Отправка/получение данных из php COM-port и обратно через c#

Tags: php, c#, .net, веб-сервер

Возникла такая задача. Нужно обратиться из php в приложение работающее через com порт (с вызовом dll библиотеки) и получить обратно от него ответ.
Я решил написать в качестве посредника, скажем роутера небольшое приложение на c#.
Которое должно работать следующим образом.

Из php через curl(json or xml) я обращаюсь к приложению на c#, приложение на с# принимает данные, парсит и отправляет эти же данные в приложение работающее через com порт, получает ответ из этого приложение данные, и обратно отправляет ответ из приложения в php скрипт.

Самая большая проблема в том, что я очень слабо знаком с возможностями c#.

Нужна помощь в получении данных из php скрипта и отправки обратно в php скрипт например принятые данные из php.

Я нашел небольшой сниппет на c# принцип которого меня устраивает, но я как получить отдать ответ я не знаю. Прошу оказать мне помощь.

P.S как обратиться  к com порту я уже наковырял )

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
        // установка адресов прослушки
        listener.Prefixes.Add("http://localhost:8888/connection/");
        listener.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Wait..");
        // метод GetContext блокирует текущий поток, ожидая получение запроса 
        HttpListenerContext context = listener.GetContext();
        HttpListenerRequest request = context.Request;
        // получаем объект ответа
        HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;
        // создаем ответ в виде кода html
        string responseStr = "test";
        byte[] buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseStr);
        // получаем поток ответа и пишем в него ответ
        response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
        Stream output = response.OutputStream;
        output.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        // закрываем поток
        output.Close();
        // останавливаем прослушивание подключений
        listener.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("End");
        Console.Read();

    }
```

Нужен временный айпи и порт на который я буду обращаться из php, что мне предоставляет сниппет http://localhost:8888/connection/.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а зачем так сложно? почему сразу не писать в ком порт из РНР?

Comment: Нужно вызывать dll, я это переложил на сторону c#, на php это целая морока, одна библиотека для вызовов dll которую уже никто не поддерживает

Comment: вы можете сделтаь простенький веб сервер на [asp.net core](https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/) и запускать его из командной строки

Comment: Теоретически я знаю об этом ) Дайте  пожалуйста если есть ссылки на то как я могу принимать пост данные,json в c# просто обращаясь к нему по ипадрессу, типа var_dump($_POST) на php какой-нибудь.
Может я не так искал, но все что я находил это как слушать какой-либо адресс на поступление сообщений. Тобишь есть сервер с которого ждешь ответ. А мне наоборот. Сервер который ждет любой запрос (raw,json, xml)

Comment: я вот этого просто не понял - `Тобишь есть сервер с которого ждешь ответ. А мне наоборот. Сервер который ждет любой запрос (raw,json, xml)`. Пишете веб сервер, самый простой, этот сервер висит на конкртеной машине и конкретном порту. Шлете туда запрос (raw, json, xml - что хотите), сервер запрос принимает и обрабатывает и что то делает.

Comment: Ваш дальнейший пост пояснил мой не много запутанный вопрос. Именно это мне и нужно. Я в принципе это и собираюсь сделать. У меня проблема именно в принятии и отправке обратно данных(я не знаю как это делать на с#) Сейчас почитаю то что вы посоветовали. Спасибо

Comment: почему не COM (OLE) тогда, например?

Comment: @teran, не совсем понял, что имелось ввиду.

Comment: это имелось в виду, http://php.net/manual/ru/class.com.php , если у вас винда, конечно. Не ясно, зачем взаимодействовать через сеть.

Comment: @teran, аа, понял. Да я читал про это. Это все не то. Мне нужно работать с dll от программки, это в принципе по документации я делаю. У меня единственная проблема принимать и отсылать обратно данные в c# программе.
Нужен аналог file_get_contents("php://input"); на c# , по веб серверу я почитал, заморочек там много, мне бы маленькое решение принял и отдал, и все.

Comment: чем не то? вы пишете обертку над длл. не важно будет эта обретка прдедставлять вэб-приложение (как вы делаете) или другую ком библиотку. В последнем случае просто исключается сеть как промежуточное звено обмена данными.

Comment: Я впервые создаю тут тему, поэтому каюсь, не знал что все должно быть в одной ветке, редактирование вопроса не нашел, поэтому вынуждено дополнил тему новым ответом (искренне не понимаю, почему нельзя) не суть, всем спасибо за внимание. Снимайте вопрос. 
А Вам товарищи желаю больше терпимости.

Answer (score 0):

```
$fp = fopen('PORT', 'r+');
```

где PORT - адрес порта в системе.
Дальше просто читать писать в этот файл стандартными средствами.
Никаких C#, серверов, dll, XML, JSON и прочей чепухи.

Comment: да не знает человек API для работы с подключенным устройством. Есть описалово у него только длл-ки работающей с устройством.